# Firefox sends triple request for the first time load of a page

Tags: node.js, firefox, request, response

I am new to NodeJS.
I was practicing the below sample code.

```
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
http.createServer(function(request,response){
        console.log("request hit "+ ++count);
        response.writeHeader(200,{"content-type":"text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        console.log("Request served", count);
        response.end();
    }).listen(8050);
console.log("Server running on 8050");
```

The output in firefox for the first hit.

> ```
> request hit 1
> Request served 1
> request hit 2
> Request served 2
> request hit 3
> Request served 3
> ```

On reloading the page, single response is received in Firefox.

Can anyone tell me the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. With these answers I will include mine which I found.

Firefox sends two request for favicon. The reason is that, Firefox functionality is to consider the favicon of chrome browser too.

I found this in "about.config" page of firefox.  In that page, I can see "browser.chrome.favicons" and "browse.shell.shortcutsFavicons". On disabling two favicons, i can now get only one request all the time.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is first request, firefox will get the page. One the next request(s) firefox will get the `favicon.ico`. Next time page is refreshed, firefox has already cached `favicon.ico` and it won't request for it again, so it will just get the page only.

Answer (score 0):

Second request is probably `GET /favicon.ico`. Third could be initiated by some plugin. You can figure that out by printing [`request.method`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method) and  [`request.url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url).

Comment: But in the second request, `count` is incremented only once.

Comment: I would do what @elmigranto suggested and log `request.method` and `request.url`, that usually makes it easy to spot favicon.ico and similar requests.

Comment: @viki888 that is correct behaviour, request are processed sequentially, one by one, in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look to the urls...

```
server running on 8085>
Count: 1
GET
/
Count: 2
GET
/favicon.ico
Count: 3
GET
/favicon.ico
```

So seens to be like firefox is asking for /favicon.ico twice and in the second request firefox already cached this url.

The behaviour is similar in google chrome, but chrome just do one request for get / and get /favicon.ico so in chrome you have 2 request.

Is interesting why firefox is doing 2 request for favicon.ico maybe if the first request to /favico.icon fails it try it again.

Seems to be a known issue [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403408)

Comment: So you are saying that, on refreshing the page, Chrome also will send only one request? The thing is that, in firefox, on refresh, one request is sent. But on chrome, for every refresh, two request is sent.

Comment: yes, seems like chrome is smart enough to know that It does not have any favicon.ico file for that page. If you clear the cache on FF and restarted you gonna see how firefox request again for the favicon.ico so my guess is that firefox in some way remember that he already asked for favicon.ico. Would be nice to try to serve a favicon.ico to know is chrome is asking always for favicon or just when it doesnot have any ico file.